# How to install google.cloud.functions_v1 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

In order to use auto-completion for Python in vscode I type-annotate my functions parameters:

A `google-cloud-function` when triggered has the following type signature:

```py
from google.cloud import functions_v1

def my_function(data: Dict[Text, Any],
                context: functions_v1.context.Context) -> None:
    ...
```

Is it possible to install the `google.cloud.functions_v1` package?

Checked on the [gcloudpypi](https://pypi.org/user/gcloudpypi/) page and there is no package available.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible. I've filed an internal feature request to open-source these types as a `google-cloud-functions` package, and will update this answer if/when this happens.

Comment: Is it possible to typehint this at all ? I installed the package that you've referenced there and don't see a way to type hint it still, `from google.cloud import functions_v1` doesn't have `functions_v1.context.Context`

Answer (score 2):

I found this library: `functions-framework` on `GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python` github repository.

As it is a namespace package, you can import it by using the following snippet:

```py
$ pip install functions-framework
...
$ pip freeze | grep functions-framework
functions-framework==2.1.3
$ python
>>> import google.cloud.functions.context
>>> google.cloud.functions.context.Context
<class 'google.cloud.functions_v1.context.Context'>
```

So for your code:

```py
import google.cloud.functions.context as functions_context

def my_function(data: Dict[Text, Any],
                context: functions_context.Context) -> None:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Google Cloud Functions API client library via pypi

https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-functions/

I can then access the functions_v1 type annotation and function attributes in my editor which is PyCharm here:

[image]